# Why isn't "innerHTML" working when I try to insert onclick events on all the items of an array using the "forEach" method?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a text and add an onclick event with a function on each word of the text. It works perfectly with some sentences, but it doesn't with others. When it doesn't work, part of the html tags are displayed on the page. I noticed that it never works when there are repeated words or when I use the words "a" or "an", but I don't know why.
Here is how I am doing it:

1. I enter the text in the page using a textarea tag.

`<textarea id="text-input"></textarea>`

2. Then I grab the text, split it into an array with all the words and add an onclick event with a function to each word.

   ```
   function addLink(){
     let text = document.getElementById('text-input').value
     const words = text.match(/\w+/g)
     words.forEach(word => {
        text = text.replace(word, `<span onclick=showWordDetail('${word}')>${word}</span>`)
    })
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text
   }


   function showWordDetail(word){
     let wordDetail = document.getElementById('word-detail')
     result = `<h3>${word}</h3>`
     return wordDetail.innerHTML = result
   }
   ```
3. The "addLink" function is called when I submit the text.

`<button onclick="addLink()">Submit</button>`

If I enter, for example, "My brother is engineer". It works perfectly. The onclick event is added to all the words.

But if I enter "My brother is an engineer", this is the result:

"an onclick=showWordDetail('My')>My brother is an engineer."

I console.log'ed the array of all my attempts and the text is split correctly. So I have no idea why sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. It avoids some of the problems of the answers that just split at spaces.

```js
const wordDetail = document.getElementById('word-detail'),
  input = document.getElementById('text-input'),
  result = document.getElementById('result');

function addLink() {
  result.innerHTML = input.value.replace(/\w+/g,`<span onclick="showWordDetail('$&')">$&</span>`)
  
}


function showWordDetail(word) {
  wordDetail.innerHTML = `<h3>${word}</h3>`
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text-input"></textarea>


<button onclick="addLink()">Submit</button>

<div id="result"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="word-detail"></div>
```

Comment: A bit buggy if the words include single quotes

Comment: Single quotes aren't matched by \w so I think it's OK.

Comment: `d'Artagnan` shows `d` and `Artagnan` when clicked - both get linked

Comment: @mplungjan true. That's a drawback. But quotes work and there's no html injection.

Answer (score 0):

> My brother is an engineer

So this includes the word `an`.

Now look at what you replaced `My` with:

> ```
>  <span onclick=showWordDetail('My')>My</span>
> ```

So when you get to `an` what is going to be replaced?

What is the first place that the sequence of characters `an` attpears?

The `an` of the `<span>`

---

You would probably be better off with something like:

```
const html = words.map(word => `<span ....>${word}</span>`).join(" ");
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html
```

where you build a new set of HTML piece by piece instead of trying to replace the old content piece by piece.

Comment: At first I struggled to understand the problem, but now it's clear and obvious. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use split() instead, with separator space and replace every word, after replace it, add it to text value like that:

```js
function addLink(){
   let text = document.getElementById('text-input').value;
   const words = text.split(" ");
   text = "";
   words.forEach(word => {
       text += word.replace(word, `<span onclick=showWordDetail('${word}')>${word}</span> `);
       
   });
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text;
 }
 
function showWordDetail(word){
 
  let wordDetail = document.getElementById('word-detail');
  wordDetail.innerHTML = `<h3>${word}</h3>`;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text-input"></textarea>
<button onclick="addLink()">Submit</button>
<p id="result"></p>
<div id="word-detail"></div>
```

Comment: This is not efficient `text += word.replace(word, \`<span onclick=showWordDetail('${word}')>${word}</span>\`) + " "; ` no need to replace - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68017376/295783) for a map version

Comment: Im replacing every word and adding to text, yes the map is good method for do that.

Comment: No need for the replace. Just `text += \`<span onclick=showWordDetail('${word}')>${word}</span>\`` will do the same as your code

Comment: If i do that the result text will be joined, without spaces, no ?

Comment: I added a space to the span. Which is why my map is what I recommend